# Errors on start of Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, ide

newbie in Kotlin. I was absent from Android Studio for a while and now restarting. I have some unfinished project and decided to continue them. So something happened with the IDE. I uninstalled it. Did a new install and now I can't even run a new project. A fresh start project already starts with errors. The color red is all over the place, including the imports. I have reinstalled the ide 3 times already, including cleaning the PC with CCleaner, but no can do. I'm having a hard time with the coding as it is :). Any clue on what can be done will be greatly apprciated.

[screenshot as the IDE starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B4Ai.jpg)
[list of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNXV5.jpg)

Comment: please add your build.gradle files

Comment: thank you for your interest Nazarii. I solved the problem by creating a new user in windows and installing the IDE there. So, I think the problem could have to do with files in my user folder.